# How to view all implementors of a given interface in NetBeans for Java?

Tags: java, netbeans, hierarchy

I'm trying to evaluate NetBeans, being a veteran Eclipse user. In Eclipse I could press F4, and I would a class hierarchy for a given class or Interface. For example - show me all the classes that implements InputStream.
It's also important it will show me this across all my dependencies and not just my code.

Comment: It works now! Tested on NetBeans 8.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: This bug has been marked as fixed, so you should be able to use Find Usages for this.

Original post: You cannot do this without some sort of plugin or other program. The inability to find usages in libraries has been under discussion for 10 years and is [currently listed as a Priority 1 enhancement](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55291), having no easy workaround. No planned fix date has been announced.

Answer (score 9):

Try this, select the type e.g. "String", then click with the right mouse button -> Navigate -> Inspect Hierarchy. On the right side you will see a window called "Hierarchy" or maybe just a vertical text with "Hierarchy" which is a minimized window (click to open).

If opened you see a combobox with "Supertypes". Change this to subtypes, there you see all classes or interfaces implementing/extending your interfaces or extending your classes.

Comment: This comment should be accepted as answer. Thank you @Sempfer

Answer (score 6):

Try this,

```
ctrl + alt + click
```

this will list all implementations of same interface

Comment: Doesn't work on a code which is not my code (a third party dependency)

Comment: This One Works fine in 8.x

Answer (score 2):

The shortcut key "Alt+F12" works for me in NetBeans 8.0.2.
I believe "Inspect Hierarchy" is in existence since NetBeans 6.0
http://wiki.netbeans.org/Java_MembersAndHierarchyPopup
Select "Subtypes" and "Refresh".
[NetBeans Type Hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrYgK.png)

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the Interface name

> Go To > Implementations(s)

Comment: It's Go To -> Implementation (single not plural), and it doesn't work - nothing happens.

Comment: You'll probably have to attach sources. Open a class from your third-party dependency and look for the toolbar at the top saying "Attach sources"

Comment: It's a Maven project and all sources are present. Also Eclipse shows me a tree with many levels of hierarchy, so you can find that interface I is implemented by A which is then extended by B, which is then extended by C. Implementations will only show 1st level. Am I missing something?

Comment: for me: netbeans 11: it is right click on interface name > Navigate > Go To Implementation and works a treat. Also the short cut ctrl + alt + click from @ravindra

Answer (score -1):

You can use "Find Usage" (select the name of the interface in your code and ALT+F7). In the popup, select "Find All Subtypes" and in the Scope, select "Open Projects".

That will show you all you all the classes that implement the interface in all your open projects.

Comment: Doesn't search libraries like asker needs to, see my answer.